# Meaning of "Carrots aren't that great" in the sentence

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms, meaning-in-context

I was reading "10 hurdles to Windows 10 adoption". In [slide 12](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3029659/microsoft-windows/10-hurdles-to-windows-10-adoption.html#slide12), there's this paragraph:

> I still think it’s smartest for Windows 7 customers to stand pat,
>   unless they see something in Windows 10 that’s absolutely
>   irresistible. **The carrots in the current version 1511 aren’t that
>   great for most.** Microsoft’s infuriating push to Get Windows 10, and
>   its uneven handling of the new Windows-as-a-service paradigm show the
>   need for a whole lot of maturing, both in the product and in the way
>   it’s handled.

I guess "carrots aren't that great" here means the features aren't good enough. Correct?

**What's the real expression used here? Is it common?**

Comment: As an aside, I find the window management in 10 to be a significant improvement over that in 7 and 8, at least in regard to tiling. Also the improvements to cmd.exe. So those are some carrots the average user won't find attractive but power users will.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here, *the carrots* refer to attractive features that might lure you into adopting the new version. It comes from the idiom [*carrot and stick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot_and_stick). To induce someone to do something you can promise a reward, the *carrot*, threaten punishment, the *stick*, or do both. There’s an analogy here to trying to make a horse or donkey go forward. Thanks to Todd Wilcox for the picture suggestion.
[image]

Comment: A picture might be worth 1000 words here: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HkVHCG9-SMY/maxresdefault.jpg The idea is that there are two ways to make a horse move, lead it from the front with a carrot or hit it from behind with a stick. It's a widely used metaphor for the balance between positive and negative encouragement/enforcement. +1

Comment: @Todd Wilcox - I guess I'm missing some context, but why is that baseball player riding a horse? That picture is indeed worth a thousand words, all of which make up a line of questioning about animal cruelty and MLB.

Comment: @Matt I'm guessing it's an attempt to draw a [polo jockey](http://pololine.com/fotogalerias/jockeyclubopen-432-2011-9-16/26.jpg) by someone who is more familiar with baseball than with polo.

Comment: Interesting, I always thought the "stick" in that idiom was the one the carrot was attached to. Seems I was wrong...

Comment: @R.M. Maybe that's a baseball player that's late for his game.

Comment: @ToddWilcox That image is worth 1000 words indeed, thanks. I've never seen anyone actually dangling a carrot in front of a horse to make it move though. I wonder whether people really used to do it.

Comment: Ya' can't beat that with a stick!!

Comment: @Jacinto - I think it was more apt to be a donkey than a horse.

Comment: Re that particular image, I would guess that it was originally drawn as an illustration for an article on some baseball team, with the carrot/stick analogy being drawn to the actions of the team's management.