# A one word substitute for "good feature/ attribute"

Tags: single-word-requests

A one word substitute for "good feature/ attribute"

For eg:
Being widely known for a "good reason" is called "FAMOUS"; whereas,
Being widely known for a "bad reason" is called "NOTORIOUS"

In that Context,

The problems/poor features of a product, will be stated under the title "ISSUES"
For eg: 
Issues: leakage, poor quality etc.

Similarly, when something has good features/ attributes; those will be stated under the title "good features" - so, what will be a good one word substitution for "good features/ attribute"

Comment: _Carrots_ can mean good things. See: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/308144/50044

Comment: How about *pros and cons*?

Comment: I don’t see anything wrong with “Features and Issues”

Comment: Use the word "virtues".

Comment: *Feature* already has the connotation of something good - hence the popular saying that something is *a feature, not a bug*. Are you looking for more than this?

Comment: In the case of a product, a piece of writing or a person you could use _strengths_. For example "The excellent build quality of the Z70c washing machine is one of its strengths"; "Clear presentation of the arguments is one of the strengths of this paper" or "His capacity for analytical thought is one of his strengths".

Answer (score 1):

I would use [benefits](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/benefit) as the opposite of issues in your context.

> *noun* 1. something that is advantageous or good; an advantage
>
> *He explained the benefits of public ownership of the postal system.*

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check ***differentiators***.

businessdictionary.com:

> **[differentiators](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/differentiators.html)**
>
> Unique features and/or benefits of a product, or aspects of a brand,
>   that set it apart from competing products or brands.

Comment: This suggestion doesn't carry any positive connotations, it is rather neutral without more context.

Comment: @Matt What connotation does _benefits_ have?

Comment: What connotation does *features* have? In this context, none.

Comment: @Matt, _features that set it apart_.

Answer (score 0):

For the good features, you might try "Qualities" as a header.

A couple of definitions of the noun [*quality*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/quality) include:

> –An inherent or distinguishing characteristic
>
> –That which makes, or helps to make, anything such as it is; anything belonging to a subject, or predicable of it; distinguishing property, characteristic, or attribute; peculiar power, capacity, or virtue; distinctive trait

Although a quality could be a negative characteristic, I think that people tend to think of the positive aspects of a thing when they think of its qualities.

Answer (score 0):

Building on a couple of comments and adding my own suggestions:

virtues

advantages

merits

pluses

good points

strengths

benefits

Comment: Would you really say that the ability to simultaneously edit a document (for example) is a **virtue**?

Answer (score 0):

**Asset** is the term I would use. In the financial usage, assets can be positive or negative, but in the common usage it's defined

> a useful or valuable thing, person, or quality

Answer (score 0):

specialty
Note, something may have several specialties, things that it performs well.

> 4.a special or distinguishing feature or characteristic.
>  [Collins Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/specialty)
>
> 6.special or distinctive quality or state.
>  [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/specialty)
>
> 1:a distinctive mark or quality
>  [Merriam-Webster
>   Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specialty)

Example:

> The P28 Splendour Blender has many specialties: a reliable and powerful
>   2000w motor, modular construction for easy cleaning and ergonomically placed controls for selecting exactly what you need.

Of course, most blenders do the same thing, so this may be a type of puffery. But, well it's a good blender.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I can tell, there doesn't appear to be a perfect synonym for 'good quality/characteristic'... In fact my own search for one brought me here.
Though depending on context, you might get away with some of these imperfect alternatives: benefit, asset, plus, value, credit, advantage & merit